# Problem with LC_TIME translations on CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, caketime

I have a cakephp 2.9 multilanguage app and using .po files for translating strings like __('example'). So far so good but I've been trying for a while now to translate this date from:

Fri, Aug 31st 2018, 16:03

to:

Vie, Ago 31 2018, 16:03

This is my code:

```
          setlocale("LC_ALL", "es_ES.UTF-8");
          App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
          echo CakeTime::nice();
```

I've downloaded the spanish files from the localized repo (https://github.com/cakephp/localized) and put them into app\Locale\spa\LC_TIME and still the date keeps showing in english.

Can someone help me? Maybe it's the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

Well, didn't took me long after I posted the question to realize all the ways I have tried were ok, using caketime or strftime directly, the problem was with the setlocale:

Changed this:

```
setlocale("LC_ALL", "es_ES.UTF-8");
```

to this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.utf8','esp');
```

So my two results are:

```
echo ucfirst(strftime('%A '.$number_of_the_day.' %B %Y'));
//Viernes 31 agosto 2018

echo __('Today is ').CakeTime::nice();
//Hoy es vie, ago 31st 2018, 16:29
```

It worked like a charm, however I'd very much like a table where all this language codes are explained so we can use the right syntax for each and not guess, just like I did.